# Ubuntu 22.04 VM freeze on VMware workstation 16

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

Every programmer needs to have a developer machine to start. one of them is to prepare VM for others. for example, we need to install Odoo ERP in every ubuntu new version for all team members.

I have a scratch installation of `Ubuntu 22.04` over `VMware workstation 16`.

My host is `Windows 10`.

After a while of using the VM, it started to freeze after a couple of minutes of usage, each time.
In some cases, before the VM froze, I've noticed some of my applications get to 100% CPU, which should never happen. When trying to debug it using `perf` the VM froze once again, so I wasn't able to see why my apps got to 100%.

Why does my VM freeze?

Comment: After 4 days of trying to fix the freeze issue, finally I open and run my virtual disk with Virtual Box. and fixed my problems.

Comment: I think your problem come from windows KB5017308. Uninstall it.
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMWare-Workstation-16-Pro-Ubuntu-22-04-1-VM-unresponsive-with/m-p/2930676#M177704

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why, but unmarking `Accelerate 3D graphics` of `Virtual Machine Settings -> Display -> 3D graphics` solved the problem.
I have an `NVIDIA GeForce MX450` on my host.

Comment: That didn't fix it for me, it still "freezes" after short period of time. but on top of that the UI responsiveness is abysmal sinde graphics acceleration has been turned off

Comment: @Svilen did your problem solved? I add comments on another answer here and try to tell my story.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi unfortunately not... You are saying that the problem is not reproducible using Virtual Box instead of VMware player to run your VM?

Answer (score 3):

I think it must be something to do with the 3D Graphics, it happened to me.

But i have and AMD RX 6700XT,

Also you can try updating the drivers for your graphics card and maybe unmarking the 3D Graphics option

Comment: in my case, I unmark 3d graphics but the problem didn't solve and again and again, after suspend and hibernate occurred then I disable hibernate but then froze. after that, I increase and decrease the RAM in VM but not solved the problem. after all, open the virtual disk with the Virtual box and solved it.